# Azure Media Services in WebAPi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-media-services

I am working on a WEB API that will consume on .NET MVC Website and Mobile Device(iOS & Android). The project is related to social networking site. In this project, user can upload video and they can play video on website as well as on their mobile device.

For this type of requirement client purchase Azure Server for hosting and he also take `Azure media services`.

My API just returning, saved video url from the server. So, my question is that where do, I write code on WebAPI side,.NET MVC side or Mobile application to stream video frequently?
I haven't any idea about this. Please help me. where from i will start.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you are looking for a way to upload content from your Mobile App and have your middle tier control the encoding and publishing of the content correct?

In that scenario you have several options.  You can use the Azure Media Services .NET SDK directly in your middle tier to submit encoding jobs, wait for encodes to complete and then publish the assets all in the mid-tier.

Or a simpler option may be to leverage Azure Functions. Your mobile application could just upload the content to a storage container (using the Azure Storage APIs for your specific App language) and then you could push a message into an Azure Queue, or call the Function via HTTP directly, or set up a Blob Trigger to run the Function app whenever a file is uploaded to a specific container.  From there, you could kick off the encode job and use Web Hook notifications to call a second function when the job is complete.  In a second function (called by the webhook from Azure Media Services after the job is done), you could then publish the asset (with whatever settings you like) and get the Streaming URL.

You would then need to update your Database for your application with the published Streaming URL and Asset information for tracking. Your mobile app would then query your mid-tier to display the streaming URL in the App's player.

We have a collection of "Sample" functions for Media Services on Github to get you going: http://aka.ms/amsfunctions

Hope that helps get you started. Let me know if you have more questions.

-John

Comment: i have not problem to upload video i already did. problem is, how to stream video on website and mobile?

Comment: Once you have the streaming Locator for the Asset, you should be using the Azure Media Player in your Website.  For Mobile, if it is iOS, you can stream native with the built in player using the HLS streaming URL from the locator, and on Android, you can use a variety of players that support DASH (but watch out for all of the legacy device issues- as Android was/is a complete mess).

Comment: See more documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-develop-video-players

Comment: AMP docs are here as well of course - https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure Media Services Player.  This is a Javascript Player that can be used on any web page.  For your mobile stuff, wrap the player in a WebView.

If you want a sample, check out Chapter 7 of my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook.

Comment: with regards to Chapter 7 first image - administrator uploading the video, if I'm trying to do the upload from a web app, do I need to get the file from the client side on to the server and then push that to azure? Or is there a way to just push the file directly from my client to azure and update a progress bar? Would you have any sample code for the upload you can share?

Comment: There are samples in the Azure Media Services and the Amazon Storage samples.